# Ansible RDS module doesn't find AWS-RDS instance

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that is trying to use the AWS RDS module to get facts on an RDS instance.  The playbook only kind of works.  When being run against localhost, as follows, it works just fine:

```
  - hosts: localhost
    connection: local
    gather_facts: False
    tasks:
    - name: look up info for {{ env }} - {{ store }}
      rds:
        command=facts
        instance_name="postgres-{{ env }}-{{ store }}"
        region={{ region }}
      register: rds
      until: rds.instance.status == "available"
      retries: 30
      delay: 60

    - name:  debug it
      debug:  msg="{{ rds.instance.status }}"
```

It shows that the status is "available".  However, if I run it against another machine (one of my EC2 instances), it says the database doesn't exist.  So, this doesn't work:

```
  - hosts: tag_app_utility:&tag_store_ops:&tag_env_{{ env }}
    tasks:
    - name: look up info for {{ env }} - {{ store }}
      rds:
        command=facts
        instance_name="postgres-{{ env }}-{{ store }}"
        region={{ region }}
      register: rds
      until: rds.instance.status == "available"
      retries: 30
      delay: 60

    - name:  debug it
      debug:  msg="{{ rds.instance.status }}"
```

Any ideas on why it may only work on localhost?

Comment: Does the host in the second case have boto installed, and since you're not passing EC2 credentials as parameters to the task, do you have the proper credentials set up for boto on that host as well?  What is the output of running the second playbook with -vvvv?

Comment: Credentials!  Ugh.  That was it.  I forgot to add the RDS credentials to the IAM user associated to the host.  Thanks, Bruce!

Answer (score 0):

As Bruce P mentioned, it was credentials.  Never forget to check your IAM credentials.